# SQL DDL To make a delete with certain features

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I want to create a table which contains foreign key called quantity_ID and make the delete on cascade but block the delete if any of the tuples in referenced tables contains cost greater than 100 
I want to it in the simplest possible way 
i.e. is it possible to done by merging constraint on delete with a query ?

Comment: Please recreate the tables with some sample data using http://sqlfiddle.com and give your expected output based on that.

Comment: Posting an **I want** question without showing efforts is not a good practice. So, have you tried anything, show your effort you spent looking for a solution first, and show us your effort output so that we can continue in helping you solve your issues.

Comment: Actually it can be done using triggers ,Here I'm searching for a simpler way